# NODE.JS some errors occur my server

Tags: mysql, node.js

errors

```
{ [Error: connect ENETDOWN]

 code: 'ENETDOWN',

 errno: 'ENETDOWN',

 syscall: 'connect’,

 fatal: true }



{ [Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL]

 code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL’,

 errno: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL’,

 syscall: 'connect',

 fatal: true }



{ [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT]

  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT’,

  code: 'ETIMEDOUT’,

  syscall: 'connect',

  fatal: true }



{ [Error: connect ENETUNREACH]

  code: 'ENETUNREACH’,

  errno: 'ENETUNREACH’,

  syscall: 'connect',

  fatal: true }
```

i get this error. but i don't know why this error occur.. 
 now i use mysql generic-pool express. it's so simple server.
 any idea for this errors ??

Comment: could you show us some of the server code?

Comment: What port are you running the server on? My guess is you're trying to run the server on a port that is already in use or one that requires root/administrator previleges, or you're listening on an incorrect host

Comment: thank you for your answer ! could you tell me your mail? i send my server code to your mail!

Comment: could you just tell us which port you're listening on and if you're running it with root/administrator priveliges? I'm not too excited about giving my email address on a public website

Comment: oh i am sorry ! i use http-proxy and use 80 and 3000 port! and i am runnig my server on root/administrator priveliges..

Comment: well, try running it on different ports, and see if that works

Comment: thank you @Markasoftware. i resolve this problem trying another port.